# How do the Telnet requests "DO" and "WILL" differ?

Tags: protocol-theory, rfc

I am implementing a Telnet client using [RFC 854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854).
I read about the negotation syntax (`DO`, `WILL`, `WON'T`, etc.) and am confused by this paragraph:

> In summary, `WILL XXX` is sent, by either party, to indicate that
> party's desire (offer) to begin performing option `XXX`, `DO XXX` and
> `DON'T XXX` being its positive and negative acknowledgments; **similarly,
> `DO XXX` is sent to indicate a desire (request) that the other party
>
> (i.e., the recipient of the `DO`) begin performing option `XXX`, `WILL XXX`
> and `WON'T XXX` being the positive and negative acknowledgments.  Since
> the NVT is what is left when no options are enabled, the `DON'T` and
>
> `WON'T` responses are guaranteed to leave the connection in a state
>
> which both ends can handle.**  Thus, all hosts may implement their
> TELNET processes to be totally unaware of options that are not
> supported, simply returning a rejection to (i.e., refusing) any
> option request that cannot be understood.

<sub>(Emphasis and code formatters added.)</sub>

I have two questions, one per emphasized sentence:

1. What is the difference between the `WILL` and `DO` request? They can apparently be used by either party ("[...] `WILL XXX` is sent, **by either party** [...]") and they only differ in that their "desire[s]" are an "offer" for the former and a "request" for the ladder. But what's the difference? I searched the RFC for "offer" for more information but it appears only that single time.
2. I don't understand the reasoning in the second sentence ("Since the NVT is what is left when no options are enabled [...]"). I thought the NVT (Network Virtual Terminal) was an abstraction of a concrete terminal, so the Telnet protocol does not need to worry about the concrete terminals' quirks on both sides? How can it be "left" then? That means it can be augmented by the Telnet options but I don't get what that means at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You send `WILL` if you want to start performing something, and you send `DO` if you want the other end to start performing something. Think of it as `I Will` and `You DO`.

The NVT is what is in common with the terminals on both sides. If one side can do a line length of 132, but the other side can only do a line length of 80, the two sides will come to an agreement to do a line length of 80 since both sides can do that. The side that can do 132 will either send a `WILL` or a `DO` to the side that can only do 80, but it will then receive a negative response to that. The side that can do 80 can send a `WILL` or `DO` to the side that can do 132, and it should receive a positive response since the side that can do 132 can also do 80.

Don't forget to support the update ([RFC 5198](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5198)) when implementing this.

Answer (score 5):

### What is the difference between the `WILL` and `DO` request?

There is a very important concept involved here, that you need to understand when implementing a Telnet server or client, otherwise your implementation might misbehave in rather odd ways:

Every numbered option that can be negotiated actually has **two independent** sets of states associated with it - one set of states is associated with the communication from *you* (the application you are implementing, be it a client or server) to the *peer* (the communication partner that sits at the other end of the line, be it a server or client) and the other set of states is associated with the opposite direction of communication from the *peer* to *you*.

You **must** keep and handle both sets of states independently if you want to prevent negotiation loops and undesired behavior for the user.

There may be some interoperation between the both sets of states involved, depending on what the option does (you should read the particular RFC for each option you intent to support), but you best implement that on a higher level of abstraction. The basic option negotiation in both directions needs to be independent.

Let's take option 0 `TRANSMIT-BINARY` as an example. One set of states is about whether *you* will send bytes using all 8 bits (binary) to the *peer* and the other is about whether the *peer* will send binary to *you*. All 4 combinations are possible (*you* 7-bit & *peer* 7-bit, *you* binary & *peer* 7-bit, *you* 7-bit & *peer* binary, *you* binary & *peer* binary) and changing the option for one direction doesn't (directly) change the same option for the other direction.

- If **you** send an `IAC` `WILL` `TRANSMIT-BINARY`, you are talking about the direction from *you* to the *peer* and you are effectively asking the *peer* to allow you send binary. The *peer* can answer either `DO` or `DONT`.
- If **you** send an `IAC` `DO` `TRANSMIT-BINARY`, you are instead talking about the direction from the *peer* to *you* and you are effectively asking the *peer* to start transmitting binary if it is able to and willing. The *peer* can answer either `WILL` or `WONT`.
- However, if the **peer** sends an `IAC` `WILL` `TRANSMIT-BINARY` (as opposed to you sending it), it is talking about the direction from the *peer* to *you* and it is effectively asking *you* to allow it send binary. *You* can answer either `DO` or `DONT`.
- Analogously, if the **peer** sends an `IAC` `DO` `TRANSMIT-BINARY`, it is talking about the direction from *you* to the *peer* and it is effectively asking *you* to start transmitting binary if you are able to and willing. *You* can answer either `WILL` or `WONT`.

Similar things can be said about requests initiated with `WONT` and `DONT`, with the important difference that the only allowed replies to those are `DONT` and `WONT` respectively. That means options can always and at any time be turned off (while turning them on is subject to mutual agreement).

You may want to read [RFC 1143](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1143), which is suggesting a way to implement the negotiation and the associated sets of states.

### About the meaning of `NVT`

What they are talking about there is that the `NVT` is a specification of a basic set of fallback properties and behaviors. I.e. if all negotiable options are off (they are required to be off at the start of the connection and if some are turned on during the session, you can turn them all off again, if you so desire), what you have is the minimal set of defined behaviours, you are left with the functionality specified as `NVT`

Turning options on diverges from the specified basic `NVT`.

What this all means is that either end can just refuse turning on any options and then just behave in the same manner as is specified for a *Network Virtual Terminal* in the relevant RFC's and it can be sufficiently sure that the other end supports that mode of operation in some way (as operating with any and all options turned off is mandated in the standard).